# Show all error messages simultaneously in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm having a form having some validations (jQuery). They are displayed (error messages) one by one if emptied, but I want to display all the relevant error messages, whose fields are emptied.

Here is the code:

```
$("#registrationForm").submit(function() {
  if ($("#familyId").val() == "0") {
    $("#imgerror").text("");
    $("#err").text("Please select family");
    $("#familyId").focus();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;

  }
  if ($("#occupationId").val() == "0") {
    $("#imgerror").text("");
    $("#err").text("Please select occupation");
    $("#occupationId").focus();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;

  }
  if ($("#stateId,#pstateId,#cstateId,#wstateId").val() == "") {
    $("#imgerror").text("");
    $("#err").text("Please select state");
    $("#stateId").focus();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;

  }
  if ($("#caste").val() == "") {
    $("#imgerror").text("");
    $("#err").text("Please select caste");
    $("#caste").focus();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;

  }
  if ($("#code").val() == "") {
    $("#imgerror").text("");
    $("#err").text("Please enter code");
    $("#code").focus();
    return false;

  }
  if ($("#pname").val() == "") {
    $("#imgerror").text("");
    $("#err").text("Please enter name");
    $("#pname").focus();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In the beginning, set

```
msg = ""
```

Once any validations fail, collect a corresponding message for the failure.

```
msg += <your message>
```

In the end, check if `msg === ""`, then submit your form.

If message is not empty, display the message using

```
$("#err").text(msg)
```

Comment: @Archer, i do not think so it will

Comment: Now that you've completely changed your answer it will have all the messages, but it's now just a bad answer.

Comment: after making changes as you suggested, i changed `return false;` to error = true; and then i used to check as-    ` if(error){
          return false;
      }
      else{
          return true;
      } `but only last error is printed and then last second and soon

Comment: @Archer, i initially did not notice the text function as i am using it from the mobile and hence the indentations are hard to decipher. Hope you would understand. Thanks

Comment: @Prakalp, please change the solution as I have edited it. Thank you :)